# Python.NET stuck and cannot exit after executing code

Tags: python, python-3.x, .net, .net-6.0, python.net

I am trying to use Python.NET library and just trying simple code below. I use dotnet 6 and python 3.8 for this. I am running in Mac OS Monterey with M1 chip. Both python and dotnet binaries are for M1 arch already.

```
using System;
using Python.Runtime;

Console.WriteLine("Executing python...");

PythonEngine.Initialize();
// acquire the GIL before using the Python interpreter
using (Py.GIL())
{
    // create a Python scope
    using (var scope = Py.CreateScope())
    {
        string code = @"
x = 1+3
print(x)
";
        scope.Exec(code);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Finish");
```

The python code execute successfully but the program never exit (return 0). It is just hang. What is wrong with my code?